# REGEX To get seven numbers in a row?

Tags: python, regex

Just wondering what the best regex to get seven and only seven numbers in a row is? Is there a way to use `[0-9]` seven times succinctly? Or should I just use a few `???`?

The seven numbers refer to a school district id code that could appear anywhere on a school district's wiki page. **They would be separated from other content by spaces.**

Input: BeautifulSoup of these pages
NCES D id on the right in the table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anniston_City_Schools
Same thing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntsville_City_Schools

Ouptut: a seven digit number representing the district id ex: `1234567`

Comment: And what would be *around* the 7 numbers? Would `12345678` match and return the first 7 digits?

Comment: You need to provide us with sample input and expected output.

Comment: How about you look for `\d+` (or `\d{7,}` to get less false positives) and then check whether the length of the match is 7? Seems much easier than f...iddling with what the right lookahead/lookbehind is.

Comment: Also: "the number I'm looking for" is, out of context, not a great example of output. The idea is to provide the exact output that your sample inputs will produce.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use a regular expression **at all**. Use an HTML parser, like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp = urlopen(Request('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anniston_City_Schools',
                       headers={'User-Agent': 'Stack Overflow'}))
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.read())

table = soup.find('table', class_='infobox')

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    if 'NCES' in row.th.text:
        nces = row.td.a.text
        print nces
        break
```

This loads the URL data, finds the "infobox" table, then the row with the NCES entry.

There are *12* exactly-7-digit numbers in the HTML source, but the above code extracts the correct number in one go.

Comment: But what if the district page does not have an infobox and has a code (admittedly unlikely given that those which post their id's tend to be more organized and thus have an infobox...).

Comment: @goldisfine: The OP linked to 2 Wikipedia pages, stating the goal is to grab the NCES numbers. Both examples have the infobox.

Comment: @goldisfine: If there are any pages that use a different template, then the code can be adjusted for those exceptions. The regular expression route is still going to result in matching more than just the NCES code.

Answer (score 6):

This looks for 7 numbers, then makes sure the next characters isn't another number

```
\b[0-9]{7}(?![0-9])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

If you are fine with matching spaces around the entire 7 digits, this is okay too

```
\b[0-9]{7}\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

If you want to match Asad's example `NCSD Code:1234567` This should work

```
(?<![0-9])[0-9]{7}(?![0-9])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: There's a typo there: the lookahead isn't closed. Also, let's wait for the OP to clarify. This, for example, will still match 12345678. No idea if that is required.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux, [Grimm...](http://stackoverflow.com/users/662645/grim) showed them to me. You can make your own at [debuggex.com](http://debuggex.com)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
(?<=^|[^0-9])[0-9]{7}(?=$|[^0-9])
```

It will match 7 digits only, no more, no less.

Or using negative lookarounds...

```
(?<![0-9])[0-9]{7}(?![0-9])
```

Comment: You don't need `zero-width anchor OR non-digit`. Use negative lookarounds with digits. `(?<![0-9])[0-9]{7}(?![0-9])` (I'm fuzzy on the syntax, but you get the idea)

Comment: Thanks! I really need to sleep x_x

Comment: Am I out of my mind here? Is [0-9]{7}[^0-9] not a viable option somehow?

Comment: @Aerovistae No, [0-9]{7} will match the first numbers (or last) in a 10 digit number.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for

```
[^0-9]([0-9]{7})[^0-9]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/-Ve4VKUTS07q6YHv)

Comment: This actually matches the non digits, which is not required. You could take the capturing group, but this is an unnecessary complication in a regex flavor that supports lookaround.

Comment: I agree with @Asad; you should use a zero-width boundary match like `\b` or a lookaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
'\s(\d{7})\s'
```

Using Python `re` module:

```
re.findall('\s(\d{7})\s',s)
```

Testing with:

```
s = 'abc 1 abc 22 abc 333 abcd 666666 ab7777777bc 7777777 abc 88888888'
```

gives:

```
#['7777777']
```

Comment: This might not work depending on what the exact input HTML is. I.e. if the 7-digit number is enclosed in tags.

Comment: It's one of the many things the OP is confused about. They're not. (I didn't downvote BTW but that still leaves the fact this answer wouldn't do what the OP is trying to achieve, however much they're misspecifying it.)

Answer (score 0):

If your entire string is possibly just a seven-digit string, you can use the following expression. It matches exactly seven numbers, and doesn't allow for any other characters in the input (won't match against `g1234567` or `1234567g`):

```
^(\d{7})$
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters Do you mean anchoring?

Comment: Asad and Martjin, I did edit my answer to no longer possibly match an 8+ digit string. However, it's still limited in the sense that it won't match `ID: 1234567`

Comment: Well, it's good enough given the amount of information the OP originally provided. Btw you can ping people using @, so they get a message in their inbox and can revisit the thread.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest to read regex is

```
(?<!\d)\d{7}(?!\d)
```

However in Python 3 `\d` can match digits from other writing systems, so it should be preceded by `(?a)` or use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`.

Explained:

```
(?<!\d) # zero-width negative look-behind assertion
        # ensures that the following was not preceded by a digit

\d{7}   # a digit repeated exactly 7 times

(?!\d)  # zero-width negative look-ahead assertion
        # ensures that the previously matched 7 digits are not
        # followed by an eighth digit.
```

Many other answers here are plain wrong because they will fail to match for example `"1234567 blablabla"` or `"<td>1234567</td>"`.